# Volume control 'out of phase' with actual volume and Alsamixer

Tags: sound

I'm setting up a friend's HP Presario (quite old) laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 which used to work fine in 11.10. However, the volume is completely silent until it is turned up to about 3/4. Past this point, it makes giant leaps all the way up to 100% when volume is on full.

Alsamixer, however, shows this perfectly. The 'master' bar stays at zero until the normal   volume setting is past 3/4, so it's measuring actual volume perfectly. This suggests that it's a problem with Ubuntu's volume control.

EDIT - on the sound settings labelled volume slider (at the bottom), the volume seems to be zero at the 'unamplified' point (75% across the bar) and 100% at the '100%' point.

Comment: hey :) some people seem to solve this one:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/128614/volume-range-is-narrow-in-12-04

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem. I fixed this by going to configuration settings -> sound -> output i chose headphone + amplifier, on the tab hardware i selected analoge output profile instead of analog stereo duplex. With these settings, it's less out of phase.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have a hardware tab, the settings have merged and there are fewer options now.